# Functions not available in the DownscaleR package?

Tags: r, function, package

I am trying to use the downscaleR package to downscale future precipitation data, and I notice that the downscaleR package provides different methods to achieve this.
https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR

When I try to follow the delta method example, I notice the error "could not find function "quickDiagnostics".
https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR/wiki/calibration-and-cross-validation

In addition, I have followed the example "Perfect Prognosis Approach: Application to Seasonal Forecasts" available at http://meteo.unican.es/work/downscaler/wiki/html/PPapplycationSeasonalForecast.html. However, the “loadMultiField" and "plotMeanField" functions are not available.

I have loaded the packages downscaleR, transformeR, visualizeR, loadeR, climate4R.UDG, and climate4R.datasets. I wonder if the above functions have been excluded from the package, or do I need to install another package? Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the GitHub commit history:

> remove function quickDiagnostics and dependencies, committed on May 25, 2020

https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR/commit/f85ad1533d3f8579d6072e35b880b82de6c0408e

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I wonder if you are aware of why “loadMultiField" and "plotMeanField" are also not available? Thank you.